# Box2D: edge shape and chain shape use different coordinates for vertices

Tags: iphone, box2d

I'm creating a body with many vertices to collide with another bodies in the scene. This is done with `b2ChainShape`, but I first tried creating a single edge of that chain (`v2v` is the coordinates conversion method):

```
b2Vec2 v1 = [U v2v:CGPointMake(0, 150)];
b2Vec2 v2 = [U v2v:CGPointMake(50, 150)];

b2EdgeShape shape;
shape.Set(v1, v2);
```

This works as expected: other bodies collide with this edge. Strangely, when using the same vertices for the chain shape, there's no collision:

```
b2Vec2 vertices[2];
vertices[0] = [U v2v:CGPointMake(0, 150)];
vertices[1] = [U v2v:CGPointMake(50, 150)];

b2ChainShape shape;
shape.CreateChain(vertices, 2);
```

Any idea why? Do chains use some different coordinate system?

Comment: That's weird. Internally a chain shape just manages a bunch of edge shapes so there should be no difference here. Is there nothing else somewhere in your code that could be relevant?

Answer (score 0):

Please read following paragraph that I take from Box2d manual.
http://www.box2d.org/manual.pdf

> Edge shapes are line segments. These are provided to assist in making
>   a free-form static environment for your game. A major limitation of
>   edge shapes is that they can collide with circles and polygons but not
>   with themselves. The collision algorithms used by Box2D require that
>   at least one of two colliding shapes have volume. Edge shapes have no
>   volume, so edge-edge collision is not possible.